# HTML Error: Display Inline-Block, not Inline?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a website for my school, and I am working on getting a area where there is a content area and also a sidebar. As you can see here: lrch.harrisonbh.com and I want the top of "Header 1" to match the top of "Sidebar." I put the css on a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GHpux/

I am using the css code here:

```
div.body{
    width: 1047px;
    margin-top: 210px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.content{
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
    width: 750px;
    max-width: 750px;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    z-index: 1;

    display: inline-block;
}

div.sidebar{
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
    width: 215px;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

But I get the undesired effect of the divs not matching up as you can see on the jsFiddle or my website. Im wonderding what is wrong with this? Thanks. I have tried many things. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice site, by the way. Sorry I didn't see the question. The fix is:

You need to remove the `<br />` before the `.sidebar`.

Refer the screenshots.

[image: before]

Removing it makes it look this way:

[image: after]

Comment: @HarrisonHoward I have added the full code. Please see now. :)

Comment: I am Using Google Chrome, not some old browser haha

Comment: As a web designer I have to stay up to date. And use a Mac :D

Comment: Righly said. Lol Okay. What's the version. I am also using Google Chrome, but the version is 24. It looks good.

Comment: @HarrisonHoward That was a simple fix. Remove the `<BR />` before the sidebar div.

Comment: For me the sidebar looks like this: http://pbrd.co/UNBNh9. I am using version 24 also.

Comment: @HarrisonHoward I found the issue. Check out my answer now! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24224/discussion-between-harrison-howard-and-praveen-kumar)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `<br>` before sidebar, remove `position:absolute` and `float:right` from the sidebar and add `vertical-align:top` to sidebar and content.

http://jsfiddle.net/GHpux/1/

Comment: Haha, beat me to it. The `<br>` was messing it up. ^^